# return list of points within polygon geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I have a shapefile of London with over 4000 unique polygons representing lsoa areas. I have also created a geodataframe of points representing sensors in the city. I need to work out which lsoa area (ie which polygon) each sensor belongs to/is within. So ideally I would have a list of each sesnsor_id_location and their respective lsoa number (LSOA11DC).

My points look like this:

```
    pod_id_location Borough Latitude    Longitude   geometry
0   1245    Barnet  51.604486   -0.206551   POINT (-0.20655 51.60449)
1   2245    Camden  51.521880   -0.120434   POINT (-0.12043 51.52188)
2   3245    Camden  51.555485   -0.152338   POINT (-0.15234 51.55548)
3   5245    Wandsworth  51.440399   -0.186775   POINT (-0.18677 51.44040)
4   6245    Hounslow    51.468625   -0.359770   POINT (-0.35977 51.46863)
```

and my london shape file looks like this:

```
    LSOA11CD    LSOA11NM    geometry
0   E01000001   City of London 001A POLYGON ((-0.09729 51.52158, -0.09652 51.52027...
1   E01000002   City of London 001B POLYGON ((-0.08813 51.51941, -0.08929 51.51752...
2   E01000003   City of London 001C POLYGON ((-0.09679 51.52325, -0.09647 51.52282...
3   E01000005   City of London 001E POLYGON ((-0.07323 51.51000, -0.07553 51.50974...
4   E01000006   Barking and Dagenham 016A   POLYGON ((0.09115 51.53909, 0.09326 51.53787, ...
```

Visually my data looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very simple solution using a spatial join as follows:

```
merge = gpd.sjoin(map_df, sensors, how="right", op='contains')
```

```
    index_left  LSOA11CD    LSOA11NM    pod_id_location Borough Latitude    Longitude   geometry
index_right                             
0   199 E01000204   Barnet 025C 1245    Barnet  51.604486   -0.206551   POINT (-0.20655 51.60449)
1   897 E01000915   Camden 027A 2245    Camden  51.521880   -0.120434   POINT (-0.12043 51.52188)
```

Comment: Yes, a spatial join is what you want here. Just one note: you might want to switch the order? (`sjoin(sensors, map_df, op='within')` )