# How to get all Points that are inside Polygons in GeoDataFrame?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely

I have two GeoDataFrames. One contains Points, another contains Polygons.

I need to get all Points that are inside any Polygon from GeoDataFrame.

I tried iterate through all Polygons and check if Point inside this polygon or not. This solution works but it is very slow.

I wonder if there is another way to solve this task.

edit:
My solution looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(Poly_gdf.index)):
    inter = Points_gdf[Points_gdf.intersects(Poly_gdf.loc[i,'geometry'])]
    if not inter.empty:
        for i in inter['geometry'].values:
            points.append(i)
```

Comment: Have you checked this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230494/intersecting-two-shape-problem-using-geopandas

Comment: Also see: [GeoPandas: check if point is in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58513123/7851470), [return list of points within polygon geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60136349/7851470), and [Check for points within polygon from geodataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61055792/7851470).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use spatial join, which is optimised and should be fast.

[See documentation for details.](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins)

```
points_within = gpd.sjoin(Points_gdf, Poly_gdf, how='inner', predicate='within')
```

`how='inner'` might be "optional" (depending on the case).

Comment: I had error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'". I solved it by installing Rtree. Thanks. This is exectly what I needed.